# How to get id of selected item in combobox C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, forms, winforms

i am working with ComboBox in my WinForms project.
I get an attribute `LIB` from SQL server table value showed in the ComboBox.
I need to get another attribute `OID` of the selectedItem and pass it from the first Form (`FormMaster`) to another Form (`FormImport`).

```cs
con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [ID] FROM [AffecAnalytique].[dbo].[DESCRIPTIF] WHERE [LIBELLE]='" + comboBox3.Text + "' ", con);

SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (!rdr.HasRows)
{
    try
    {
        string strOIDe = rdr["OID"].ToString();
        textBox1.Text = rdr["OID"].ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(strOIDe);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { }

    MessageBox.Show("tesssssssssst");
}
else MessageBox.Show("11111");

con.Close();
```

Comment: **Warning:** That SQL is wide open to Injection attacks. You *MUST* fix that.

Comment: Start over. It is generally a huge problem to write tsql that directly refers to a specific hard-coded database. Such practice will prevent the use of multiple environments in the same instance as well as prevent using a database of a different name (such as one for clientx and one for clienty). Your connection should determine where that database exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't use an SQL like that and instead use parameters and the parameter value would be comboBox3.SelectedItem casted to actual type. The type might be a string or it might be an object with displayed text being a property of that object.

```
var selectedValue = comboBox3.SelectedItem as string; // whatever the item type is
if (selectedValue != null)
{
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@libelle", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = selectedValue;
   // your code ... 
}
```

Here is a simplified complete sample using SQL server northwind sample database:

```
void Main()
{
    DataContext db = new DataContext(@"server=.\SQLexpress2012;trusted_connection=yes;database=Northwind");
    
    Table<Category> Categories = db.GetTable<Category>();
    Table<Product> Products = db.GetTable<Product>();
   
    Form f = new Form { Text="ComboBox ornek", Height=200, Width=500 };
    ComboBox cb1 = new ComboBox{ Left=10, Top=10, Width=450, Font=new Font("Courier New",8) };
    ComboBox cb2 = new ComboBox{ Left=10, Top=60, Width=450, Font=new Font("Courier New",8) };
    
    f.Controls.AddRange( new Control[] {cb1, cb2} );

    cb1.DataSource = Categories.ToList();
    cb1.ValueMember = "CategoryId";
    cb1.DisplayMember = "CategoryName";
    cb1.SelectedIndex = -1;

    cb1.SelectedIndexChanged += (sender, args) => { 
    
    var selectedCategory = ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem as Category;
    cb2.DataSource = null;
    cb2.Items.Clear();
    if (selectedCategory != null)
    {
      cb2.DataSource = Products.Where (p => p.CategoryId == selectedCategory.CategoryId).ToList();
      cb2.DisplayMember = "ProductName";
      cb2.ValueMember = "ProductId";
    }
    };
    
    f.Show();
}


[Table(Name = "Categories")]
public class Category
{
    [Column]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

[Table(Name = "Products")]
public class Product
{
    [Column]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
}
```